# Focus an element created by a dispatch in a different part of the app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-dom

I’m writing a somewhat complex app with React and Redux, and I have a situation where clicking a button dispatches an action that creates a new DOM element in a completely different part of the app and I want this new DOM element to be focused. I’m wondering what’s the best way to do it.

I managed to make it work like this:

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  ReactDOM.flushSync(() => {
    dispatch(createNewElement(id));
  });
  document.getElementById(id).focus();
};
```

I'm using regular DOM ids to identify the element to focus and the (almost undocumented) `flushSync` function to make sure that it is actually present in the DOM when selecting it.

I cannot use refs because the new element is in a completely different component. I cannot use `autoFocus` because those elements can also be created in ways that should not be autofocused and I don’t want my HTML to be littered with obsolete autofocus's. I don’t want to put the focused state in the Redux store because it will be a nightmare to maintain properly.

Instead of `flushSync` I could also wrap the `.focus` in a `setTimeout(…, 0)`. It seems to work but I’m not entirely convinced that the element is guaranteed to be present by the time the timeout runs (unlike with `flushSync`).

**Is this a legitimate use of `ReactDOM.flushSync`? Is there another simpler way to do it?**